# Android listview position and click event handle problem

Tags: android

I have shown a dynamic listview in my Screen. In listview there are two buttons in eack row. I want to handle click event on both button. I have 50-60 rows in my listview. now when i clicked on any of the row's button it will take the position of very first row of listview. so my problem is that i have to get perfect position of clicked row. i used baseadapter but i can only able to handle one click event on each row.

so give some hint about this problem.

Comment: @harsh http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/tag/android-custom-listview-example/

Comment: @harsh in this example you can set your control in each listview item, and position will determine to handle clickevent

Answer (score 1):

public class MovietListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public int getCount() {
            return _languagechange;
        }

```
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v;
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.movielistdesign, null);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);

```
        iv.setImageDrawable(mLoader.getDrawble(position));
        iv.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        ImageView star = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.starrating);
```

star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("param1", mLoader.ds1.movie_ids[position]);
                bundle.putString("param2",
                        mLoader.ds1.movie_titles[position]);
                bundle.putString("param3",
                        mLoader.ds1.movie_thumbnailarray[position]);
                bundle.putString("param4",
                        mLoader.ds1.movie_descarray[position]);
                bundle.putString("param5",
                        mLoader.ds1.movie_rating[position]);
```